# How to find element which the same pointer to interface?

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
interface Foo
{
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
}

public class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Bar>() { new Bar(), new Bar(), new Bar() };
        Foo foo = list[2]; // let foo contains 3'th element (it is not important)
        var index = list.IndexOf(foo);  //  What's the method with similar semantics?
        Console.WriteLine($"index = {index}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Is there some builtin method/implementation of such functionality in c#?

Comment: Do you mean a language keyword that does that IndexOf does?

Comment: What are you asking?  What method with similar semantics?  What semantics are you referring to?  You already had the index.

Comment: @Amy, I Asked about method with similiar semantics

Comment: _"What's the method with similar semantics"_ Does this question makes sense for  anyone? Why you need another method?

Comment: I guess the OP is looking to find the index of element of a certain class.

Comment: Probably I've understood: Probably he want find all the object that implement the Foo interface. I always like play at Cluedo

Comment: @TimSchmelter, indexOf requers argument should be type of Bar, but I can use element of Foo type to perform lookup

Comment: Do you realize that even if your code would be accepted it will fail as all the instances in the list implement `Foo`?

Comment: @Tinwor, Yes, that's what I want! Sorry for my poor english

Comment: @Gusman, Really? I thought that pointers will be different. Maybe I missed something

Comment: @LmTinyToon I know what you asked, that didn't clarify anything *at all*.

Comment: @LmTinyToon There is no pointer involved at all, and on C#, unless you go the `unsafe` route you will never use those, you have references and implementations.

Comment: @LmTinyToon: forget pointers in C#, you are talking about instances and references. The variable `foo` references the `Bar` instance in the list, it's the same reference. That's why `IndexOf`(or my `FindIndex` approach below) works even if you don't override `Equals` meaningfully. If it's not overridden [`Object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.113).aspx) is used which just compares if two objects are the same reference.

Comment: @Gusman: What do you mean with your comment "it will fail because all objects implement Foo"? OP wants to find the index of this object even if he doesn't have a `Bar`  but a `Foo`(interface) variable. `IndexOf` doesn't support this.

Comment: That's because I didn't understood the question, it's extremely confusing, I thought he wanted to find all the classes implementing `Foo`

Comment: So it sounds like the original question was based on the fact that `IndexOf` only accepts a variable of type `Bar` but the OP only has a `Foo`... but somehow the question has (also?) become find all elements which are `Foo` in a `List<Bar>`, but because `Bar` inherits `Foo`, that's going to be all of them. Which one is the actual question?

Comment: @LmTinyToon: now i'm confused. Do you really want to search types in this list? Doesn't make sense if all of your instances are `Bar`. Is that just a bad example or do you actually want to find the `Bar` instance if you only have a `Foo` variable(interface)?

Comment: Change your list declaration to List<Foo>. You can still put Bar items in it. Research polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

To find all elements that are of type `Foo` you can use:

```
var foos = list.OfType<Foo>().ToList();
```

To find all indices of elements that are of type `Foo`, use:

```
var indices = list.Select((b, i) => new { Value = b, Index = i})
                  .Where(x => x.Value is Foo)
                  .Select(x => x.Index)
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: `Both create new collections.`

True

`The former even filters, so if you will get an index in this list it might not be the index of the item in the original list.`

Hence why I even mentioned the second bit (which preserves the original indices).

`Since you are simply casting to the interface you don't need to use OfType but Cast<Foo>`

Original question was `I want retrieve all the objects in list that implements the Foo interface. Is there a method able to do this in c#?'` That implies that not all items are of type `Foo`.